# Pandas : Removing specific dates from dataframe after a resample : frequency problem

Tags: python, pandas, date, frequency

I have a dataframe indexed by date where I removed specific dates with incoherent data. The dates that I removed are in a list date_filter. 
I want a column with the monthly mean for each day. For that I copied the column with my data in another dataframe and used the resample function :

```
df = df.resample('M', convention='start', kind='period').mean()
df = df.resample('D').pad()
```

Then I want to remove back the days in my filter list before putting back the data in my main dataframe with :

```
df.drop(date_filter, inplace=True)
```

I get the error *"IncompatibleFrequency: Input has different freq=None from PeriodIndex(freq=D)".*

The resample added a frequency to my time index and my list doesn't have a frequency since it's just random dates with no specific sequence. Any idea on how I could get rid of the frequency ? Or a better way to do what I'm trying to do ?
I thought of exporting in csv and reimporting to get rid of the frequency but it's not very "clean"...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.